# How to run extension App instead standard App in Fiori Launchpad?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have standard Fiori App `Manage Offers`.

I've created the extension of this App `Z_Manage_Offers`.

Then I deployed it to my Repository.

Now I want to run `Z_Manage_Offers` when I click the Launchpad element which early runs `Manage Offers`.

How can I do it, maybe I should change the App link or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your new app (extension app) in the Fiori Configuration admin page. You need to learn about Fiori Catalogs/Groups and Target mappings. You can google these concepts and there are enough content available online.